# É possível incluir bibliotecas dinâmicas em uma estatica?

Tags: c++, linux

O objetivo final é bem complicado, vou tentar explicar o máximo possível :

Existe o arquivo `libA.so` e o arquivo `libB.so` , ambos são necessários para utilizar o código da minha própria biblioteca `libC`, que gostaria de compilar para ser estática (.a)

Teria como eu compilar esta biblioteca e já incluir nela as dependências , sendo que elas são dinâmicas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma biblioteca estática é simplesmente uma coleção de arquivos objeto (`.o`) e não é ligada (*link*). Para verificar isso você pode rodar o comando `ar t <nome-da-biblioteca>.a`, que vai lhe mostrar quais arquivos `.o` estão incluídos na sua biblioteca estática.

Concluindo: não é possível ligar arquivos objeto ou bibliotecas estáticas a bibliotecas dinâmicas.

Comment: ok obrigado .... parece que infelizmente é isso mesmo

Comment: Se você compartilhar mais detalhes do seu problema em outra pergunta podemos tentar ajudá-lo.

Comment: vou tentar explicar o problema inteiro em uma outra pergunta